# Ratio and Proportion Maths Problem Solving

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, word-problem, ratio

A jar contains some cookies. The weight of the jar and cookies is 700g. Meghan eats $\frac{4}{5}$ of the cookies.
The weight of the jar and cookies is now 400g.
How much does the jar weigh?
How many cookies were there from the start?

What I did:
$\frac{700}{5}$ = 140

700 - 140 = 560

560 - 400 = 160

But I don't know what to do next.

Thank You and Help is appreciated

Comment: Looks a bit random and you have poor Meghan eating some of the jar. If X is the weight of the jar and Y the weight of the cookies can you write down two equations relating X and Y?

Comment: $x$ + $y$ = 700

Comment: great. how about after eating the cookies?

Comment: $4(\frac{y}{5})$ + $x$ = 400

Comment: Remember you are weighing the cookies left, not the eaten ones.

Comment: um $\frac{4}{5}$y + $x$ = 400

Comment: Ohh wait is it 1/5

Comment: Not $\frac{4}{5}y$, that is the weight you have eaten. What is left to weigh?

Comment: Sorted. Solve your equations for y and x.

Comment: $\frac{1}{5}$y + x = 400

Comment: Using simultaneous equations I found out that x = 325 so the jar weighs 325g

Comment: Job done and y is the amount of cookies you started with.

Comment: It is asking for the number of cookies I got 375 cookies but how do i use that for number of cookies.

Comment: Just a poorly worded question. There are 375g of cookies.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign letters to the unknown quantities and form simultaneous equations from them.

I would let the jar's weight be $J$ and the total weight of the cookies be $C$.

The first statement tells you:

$$J+C=700\tag 1$$

Then Meghan eats $\frac 45$ of the cookies, and the new total weight is $400g$. Can you then see that this means:

$$J +\frac15 C = 400 \tag 2$$

You now have a pair of simultaneous equations. Im sure you know how to continue this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not seem well put with respect to the **number of cookies**, as long as the weight of one cookie is not given. Let

- $j$ - weight of jar
- $n$ - number of cookies at the beginning
- $c$ - weight of one cookie

Then you have
\begin{eqnarray} 
 j + n\cdot c     & = & 700 \\ 
 j + \frac{n}{5}\cdot c & = & 400 
\end{eqnarray}
$$\Rightarrow \frac{4}{5}\cdot n\cdot c = 300$$
$$\Rightarrow n\cdot c = \frac{5}{4}\cdot 300 = 375 = 3\cdot 5^3$$

Restricting our consideration to integers you may have at the beginning, for example:

- $125$ cookies $3g$ each
- $25$ cookies $15g$ each
- $15$ cookies $25g$ each
- etc.